# LibGDX won't install on one phone, but will another

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

This is the error message, so far no amount of googling has helped find a solution.

> Error while executing: am start -n "com.simplearenagdx.game/com.simplearenagdx.game.AndroidLauncher" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.simplearenagdx.game/.AndroidLauncher }

> Error type 3

> Error: Activity class {com.simplearenagdx.game/com.simplearenagdx.game.AndroidLauncher} does not exist.

> Error while Launching activity

What I don't understand is that yes, it does exist. I can go look at it. Its there.

Comment: Try reboot-ing both devices, your computer and that phone. Time to time I'm also unable to install my app, but after restart it continues working normally.

Comment: That didn't work.

Comment: I had this problem before for the first installation of an app. Just retry and it works on second call.